# A disabled but readable input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

So I have **two forms**, one is for **creating** and the other for **editing**. Both using `method="post"`.

There's one difference between both, which is the `code_product`, that is generated via php's `rand()` function, used only when **creating** a product (so there's no code_product input here).

And when **editing** it, the `code_product` value is shown inside of an additional `input` at the top of the entire `form`.

Objective: `code_product`'s `input` mustn't be edited.

Problem: Using the `disabled` attribute makes it unreadable for **php** too.

Avoiding the asp.net (mentioned in another post), is there another way to make it uneditable, through css or javascript?

Comment: `readonly` is the attribute you're looking for most likely.

Comment: So you want it to be read-only? [`readonly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-readonly)

Comment: Be aware that you can't rely on the input to *stay* readonly if you need any kind of security. The user can trivially change the input not to be readonly

Comment: its also poor usability, the user expects input elements are editable, you should something else to simply display data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an attribute called `readonly` to your input elements. This way it cant be edited but still viewed as normal.

```
<input type="text" readonly />
```

For older browsers, you will need

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
```